# Grouping and aggregating by counts: how to keep column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example dataframe similar to the synthetic one I create below. Each ID is classified as `good` or `bad` (these could also be country codes, e.g. `US`, `ES`, `RU`, etc):

```py
In [55]: nf = pandas.DataFrame({'id': numpy.random.randint(0,100,1000)
                               ,'how':numpy.random.choice(['good','bad'],1000)
                               ,'A':numpy.random.randn(1000)
                               ,'B':numpy.random.randn(1000)
                               })

In [56]: for i in numpy.unique(nf['id'].values):
  .....:     nf.loc[nf.loc[idx[:],idx['id']] == i, 'how'] = "good" if is_odd(i) else "bad"
```

where I have defind `is_odd()` by:

```
def is_odd(num):
    return num & 0x1
```

Now, I want to do the following operations

- Group the data by IDs
- Count each group's entries / rows
- Plot a histogram of the counts for the entire population
- Plot histogram's of the counts for "good" and "bad"

For example, I would do the first two operations like:

```py
In [57]: nf.groupby(['id','how']).agg('count')
Out[57]: 
          A   B
id how         
0  bad    9   9
1  good  13  13
2  bad   16  16
3  good   8   8
4  bad    7   7
5  good  11  11
6  bad   10  10
7  good  14  14
8  bad   12  12
9  good   8   8
10 bad   12  12
...      ..  ..
```

My problem: I lose access to the columns `ip` and `how`. I can `.hist()` on the grouped result, but I cannot separate the data anymore.

Is there a smarter (not to say, correct) way of going about this?

Comment: You can probably solve this issue by resetting the multi-level index: See [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can just use [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to turn multi-index into columns:

```
In [6]: nf.groupby(['id','how']).agg('count').reset_index().head(10)
Out[6]: 
   id   how   A   B
0   0   bad   7   7
1   0  good   6   6
2   1   bad   5   5
3   1  good   5   5
4   2   bad   6   6
5   2  good   4   4
6   3   bad   3   3
7   3  good   7   7
8   4   bad  11  11
9   4  good   6   6
```

Another way to do this could be use `as_index` parameter of the [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [13]: nf.groupby(['id','how'], as_index=False).agg({'A':'count', 'B':'count'}).head(10)
Out[13]: 
   id   how   A   B
0   0   bad   7   7
1   0  good   6   6
2   1   bad   5   5
3   1  good   5   5
4   2   bad   6   6
5   2  good   4   4
6   3   bad   3   3
7   3  good   7   7
8   4   bad  11  11
9   4  good   6   6
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is there actually another way of getting a count, e.g. by inserting a `count` column? My gripe is that `A` and `B` are essentially meaningless now: they now contain row-counts, which has nothing to do with the values they used to store.